# The [protection] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I noticed the tag [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) is used for a few unrelated concepts. The main ones that stick out are:

- preventing edits on workbooks and documents
- [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) stuff: [authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization), [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking), etc

There was no tag wiki for this tag originally, and there are 420 questions at present :(

It fails all the preliminary checks before burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

**No**, the tag is ambiguous and is equally applicable to:

- branch protection (VCS)
- access control
- security measures

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes and no, the concept can be on or off-topic depending on the context (questions about protection can be about security, general computing, or asked in a programming context).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**No**, protecting something is a goal, while on-topic questions revolve around specific programming problems / algorithms that are often only circumstantially related to protection.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

**No**, the only common meaning is that it is a process of restricting access to something which, as described above, can involve completely unrelated tasks.

Comment: Added answers to preliminary burnination questions to conform the request with the established protocol - feel free to reword / edit / update as necessary for the discussion.

Comment: Rolled back because the last edits deviate from the OP original intention. If you want to make a burnination request start one from scratch.

Comment: Also those edits make the answers obsolete

Comment: Folks, given the post has been a burnination request since 2017 and is already scheduled for the evaluation process, reediting it to a retag request is highly problematic.

Comment: Agreed. If you lot have a case to make for its renaming or synonymization instead, post a new question (or an answer opposing the burnination, even though we're still months away from it actually taking place)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine How [tag:protection] was added to the evaluation process ? / What are the criteria to include a tag in that queue ? Is there a status meta-tag for tags scheduled for the burnination evaluation process? Is "still months away" another way to say in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @Rubén It's not a formal queue; it's [just a list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kfh1kOLsxd_a4mPHDvJVIV1HBbQNrAE9fvOXXSDmyMo/edit#gid=0) I use (and as the only mod coordinating burninations, that list is _the_ queue for burninations). There's no tags to represent it until the burnination process starts. But it doesn't have to start for votes and arguments for or against to take place.

Comment: "still months away" is a way to say "however long it takes to get through all the other tags in the queue". I cannot estimate that accurately, because it depends on participation numbers, which are completely unpredictable at the moment. But in general, more participants means faster burns, which means shorter waiting times for your favorite flamethrower targets:tm:

Comment: Thanks @ZoestandswithUkraine. P.S. 6-8 weeks was in reference to the old meme that, in general terms, means exactly what you explained :)

Comment: At the very least, the claim of criteria  satisfaction(which nobody seems to care about these days) should've been added as a answer instead of editing the original question.

Comment: @TheMaster as per the [official process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11407695), the justification has to be in the question, not in any of the answers. I added it in a formal manner to my understanding of the reasoning behind the original request.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's in the question or posted as an answer though. Posting answers in favor of the burn has always been allowed, and in my opinion, that includes the burn criteria if OP doesn't add them. This is with the exception of where there's no attempt to explain why the tag is bad to begin with. This question does, even though it doesn't follow the proper method, which is good enough. But I don't really mind them added to the question either.

Comment: Also, what difference does it make? If it's added to the question, which any OP can do anyway, you're free to downvote the question and dismantle it in an answer. The other alternative is downvoting the question, an answer, and dismantle the answer in the comments instead, which gets hard to keep track of real fast. The current answer trying to dismantle the criteria answering consist of 5.5k characters including formatting, which is around 9-11 comments depending on how sentences are aligned, which doesn't include the 15 replies to that answer, nor does it include the obligatory

Comment: additional comments because doing extensive dismantling in comments is hard, and thanks to reduced editing for non-mods, some extra comments may be needed to fill in that gap. I don't particularly see how that's any better

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine  `Also, what difference does it make`. The (net)upvotes for burnination was based on the previous question(which was based on previous tag wiki).  Even before it was a burnination request, when it was just a retag request, it had a +10(+12/-2) votes. Those votes can't be automatically assumed for burnination. If  the question was -50, would the proponents of burnination still have edited in the criteria or would they have made a new request? That's why it's unfair.

Comment: If the burnination was at -50, it would've been declined, forcing a new request. Your argument there is irrelevant. Since activity resurfaced, this question has still gained more upvotes than downvotes. All the opposing answers have also been downvoted below net 0. Even if it was added as an answer, you lot have currently failed to convince the  general meta core that this burnination is bad. Initial votes wouldn't have helped here when it has still gained more net upvotes than downvotes after being bumped back into activity. That's not because it's "unfair"

Comment: We're not talking about several tens or even >100 net upvotes here, we're talking about an initial net of 12. That's easy to topple if you make a solid case the meta core agrees with (or when we enter phase 2, the community at large). As evidenced by the failure to do so, your case probably isn't as convincing as you think. But we'll see what happens when phase 2 starts (or what happens in the time leading up to that; a lot can happen in a few months)

Comment: `Since activity resurfaced`. Activity surfaced when I edited the tag wiki and it started getting downvotes first(-3/+1).  Then, burninate criteria was sideloaded, which did make it gain upvotes(and my tag wiki answer was downvoted). But upvotes were still less than the burninate criteria of +20. If we remove the initial 14 votes before the criteria was sideloaded, that's just a net +7 votes. If we remove the initial 10 votes before the burn request, that's just +11 votes both well below +20 and therefore shouldn't even be considered for burnination phase 2. It matters not whether all[1/2]

Comment: the opposition answers were downvoted to -100. The tag being within 0-20 is grounds for [meta-tag:status-declined]. But sideloading improved the odds, making it pass +20 over like 5 years.[2/2]

Comment: " Then, burninate criteria was sideloaded, which did make it gain upvotes(and my tag wiki answer was downvoted)." - that assumes the burn criteria had an impact, which itself isn't guaranteed. Honestly, this just feels like a long-winded complaint about getting downvotes, and not a relevant argument. "But upvotes were still less than the burninate criteria of +20" - yes, but we don't automatically decline posts that fail to meet that threshold. They _may_ be declined, but it ain't a guarantee. it _will_. The exact wording is:

Comment: "If it does not reach the required score of 20 within 6 months, the request **may** be marked status-declined" - not "it will", it _may_.  We're also not in phase 2 yet. We're months away from phase 2, so yes, I can in fact add it to the queue and assume that it works itself out in the meanwhile.  However, discarding all votes on grounds of only being pro-retagging isn't reasonable either. And in either case, it can still be discarded in phase 2. Phase 2 does not imply a guarantee the community agrees when the time is right

Comment: imagine trying to rule lawyer community-made guidelines

Comment: However, dying on a hill of semantics is not a position I think you'd like to be in right now. Everything here has so far been up to established and defacto standards, regardless of whether you like it or not. Old, unhandled requests not hitting a score of 20 aren't guaranteed [status-declined]; adding the criteria to the question are fine (even though an answer is fine too, and what I've seen done for featured requests without the criteria listed). It now breaking +20 is also fine. Whether it should've been edited to a burn request in the first place

Comment: is something you'll have to take up with Bhargav. There's some deleted comments pointing out a dupe along with a request to retag this, which seems to make the retag itself fine as well. The only points you have here regarding the validity of the burn have nothing to do with the burnination process itself. You're welcome to try anyway, but you'd be better off spending your energy on arguments against the burn rather than its past and possible future handling

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine You're hitting a lot of strawman. I never said "It will" have to be declined. My exact words were "is grounds for status-declined". I'm establishing the fact this was a nobody cares burn request for 5 years. And therefore even +10 upvotes matter. On the negative, I couldn't compare it to -50. But, on the positive, you're comparing it to +100.  *discarding all votes on grounds of only being pro-retagging isn't reasonable either.* Why though? I'm not asking you to discard all the votes. Just the votes before the [burninate-request] was added. That sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: "I'm not asking you to discard all the votes" - never said you did. "That sounds reasonable to me" - because we have no way of proving that all the upvoters also don't side with the burnination. Disregarding their votes prevents those people from saying anything through voting. That is not reasonable

Comment: Ok, but why are their votes automatically counted "for burnination"? We have no way of proving they voted "for burnination" or just for "retagging" either.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes we should burn the [protection] tag.

Comment: Since all the current answers are no, I created this as a target for yes votes.

Answer (score 12):

[protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Security-related questions can be tagged [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security), and potentially more specific tags ([authorisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorisation), ...)
- General questions about protecting stuff (such as endpoints or files) should be tagged with relevant technologies.
- Questions about spreadsheets and protecting fields or whole sheets should be tagged with [spreadsheet-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-protection) (see [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424218/whats-the-preferred-tag-for-protection-in-spreadsheets) for details/discussion on the tag)

## Progress:

The [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=protection),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprotection%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprotection%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprotection%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprotection%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- Rodgort is still down

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Questions about spreadsheets file, sheet and cell protection, might be tagged [tag:excel] [tag:protection] or [tag:google-sheets][tag:protection]. Also [tag:google-apps-script], [tag:google-sheets-api] might be used together with [tag:protection]. These questions might require a new tag to replace the [tag:protection]. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420780/1595451. I can't develop this idea further at this time. I will try to comeback tonight.

Comment: @Rubén Given the commonality, how about just [tag:spreadsheet-protection]?

Comment: @TheMaster At first sight looks very good. I can't think more than 30 secs on this right row, sorry.

Comment: @Rubén Great. Let's retag some good questions(say 5-10), before the fire comes from the hell and burns everything.  Afterwards, we can  change or reconsider our position.

Comment: @TheMaster I agree

Comment: Note to future readers: This discussion was carried into [What's the preferred tag for protection in spreadsheets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424218)

Answer (score -2):

Despite the the tag wiki content, I don't think that we should stop using / burninate [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) as the "community" decided to clean-up the "hyphenated tags" related to tags like [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) among others, in favor of using using two or more tags.

As of January 4th, 2022:

- [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) has 600 questions
- Searching

  - `[excel] protection` returns 1584 results
  - `[google-sheets] protection` returns 618 results.

So potentially there are more questions that might properly use this tag. Just this weekend on the Google Apps Script chat room was mentioned the use of this tag as part of the current curation effort for improving the [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) with with a FAQ.

---

[protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) "should" be used together with

- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) for questions about programming issues protecting a sheet or range when [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api) is not being used, i.e. when creating a Google Workspace / Editor add-ons using the Spreadsheet Service (Class SpreadsheetApp).
- [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api) for questions about programming issues protecting a sheet or range using the Google Sheets API. Also the tag of the programming language / runtime should be used.

It should not be [merged / retagged] with / synonymized to  [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) because they have separate uses, i.e. [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) could be used for questions about access to resources in file systems like Windows, Mac Os, Google Drive,  OneDrive among others but not for protecting a spreadsheet sheet or range or a internal part of other kind of document.

I think that [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) might be used together with tags that corresponds to other spreadsheets like [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and other documents editors that also handle the protection concept separate from the access-control concept.

Actually [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) and [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) might be used together in questions about the interaction of the "access-control-list" of the file system hosting the document with the protection feature of the document editors.

Comment: I think you have an argument with the **post/keyword count** on the 2 tags, `excel` and `google-sheets`. However, isn't the word "protection" too broad to be problematic by itself? I like tags that can span multiple languages (like datatype tags `int`, `string`, `enum`) but I'm not convinced "protection" is descriptive enough and specializing the names of tags has been the trend and a safe choice. Besides, I'm suprised that "protection" seem to be a "sheets" things, isn't there lots of stuff that can be "protected"?

Comment: @bad_coder Thanks for your comment. Any suggestion about how to properly tag questions about file / sheet/ range protection in spreadsheets using "desktop" formats like Excel (xlsx) and "online" formats like Google Sheets? Could we use the same guidelines for both?

Comment: That's the problem I'm not an excel/google-sheets SME so I can't evaluate the importance/relevance of the tag. I have no ideas to contribute to this debate (besides some general burnination experience, my 2 cents are in the comment above).

Comment: A couple of years ago I "lost a battle" about tagging... what I learned is that here tag naming is more a thing of "consensus" than applying "logic" or following naming rules. On some tags the "consensus" is to keep the tag name, use the the best that you can, and don't worry about taxonomy / vocabulary / terminology correctness. Regarding [tag:protection] what I'm looking is that it won't be burninanted / blacklisted because I think that it's helpful to use it together with other tags, particularly with spreadsheet related tags, rather than creating new tags.

Answer (score -6):

Protection is a programmatic concept that can be well defined without ambiguity. After a careful review of the questions in that tag, I felt the the following definition captures the essence of the most questions in that tag. I went ahead and added the following definition:

#### Tag excerpt:

> Protection refers to any process that involves hiding the data or restricting access to the said data, such as "read only access", "write access", "copy access". Use with tags such as [c#], [php], [python], [javascript], [github] when question involves protecting code or memory. Use with [excel], [google-sheets], [sql], [passwords], [pdf] when question involves programmatic protection of data in files. Do NOT use with [data-protection]

#### Tag wiki:

> Protection refers to any process that involves hiding the data or code or restricting access to the said data, such as "view only access" or "edit only access" or "owner level access". Commonly used in

> - Preventing code-write access in github(Branch protection)
> - Preventing read/edits from a document or worksheets(like excel/google-sheets)
> - Accessing password protected pdfs programmatically.
> - Preventing unauthorized access to memory
> - Protecting unauthorized copying of code
>   by obfuscation or access control techniques

There seems to be a overlap with [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control). Whether it should be synonymized to [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) or should the tag still be burninated, or should the tag be left alone, should be determined by the community.

Comment: I don't think that [tag:access-control] and [tag:protection] should be synonymized as the first might be used when the issue refers to a file / content / database management systems like systems that relies on user accounts while the later might be used when the issue refers the file format like a password stored in the file.

Comment: The 1st thing that comes to mind when someone mentions [protected is Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_protected.asp).

Comment: Looking at data access only, it is already widely ambiguous. Write protection of files is a wildly different topic from write protection of memory-mapped addresses, which is a wildly different topic from C++ `protected` private encapsulation used during inheritance, which is a wildly different topic from buffer overrun and stack overflow protection, which is a wildly different topic from data race protection, which is-...

Comment: @Lundin I've already commented on related lines this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420781). "Wildly" is a really subjective term. Any topic, however specific, can still be subdivided into multiple "wildly" different topics. And multiple "wildly" different topics can be added as branches  to a single root. I believe burnination of parent root, just because there are multiple "wildly" different subcategories, is a mistake on principle. The main criteria is "Does it cause harm?", which it doesn't.  But the opposition has the numbers, thus the power to change the course of events here.

Comment: Well... the whole tag system is flawed by design, since it doesn't take much thought for a single person to aimlessly create a tag, but intricate rituals involving dozens of people to remove them. The majority of tags getting burninated _are_ bad and confusing though without causing much in the way of active harm other than inconsistent use. Mostly burnination is just pointless busy-work to keep the meta crowd occupied, similar to digging a hole and then filling it up again. So let them, if it makes them happy...

Comment: @Lundin I remember it didn't used to be the case. Burnination was a huge effort and requiring cooperation of multiple users. I once gathered such users, because the tag names I participated, were annoying beyond belief. I'm glad fellow users felt the same and things were done and still good(not a hole that was dug and filled up). Current users,  may have joined - probably because of a once good cause, but now seem to be doing pointless work.

Comment: @TheMaster Cleaning up domain-specific tags in an area where you have technical expertise together with similar users is a different story entirely - that's far more likely to be of longterm benefit to the site. But cleaning up broad and useless tags such as [tag:protection] is close to pointless busy-work, and nobody can be an "expert of protection", so there's no expertise to turn to either.

Comment: @Lundin I believe anyone with any experience in  the tag [protection] already made answers defending it. Those answers contained real data and logic. Those who want to burn it added nothing that's of substance, but a superficial claim that it satisfied all  the criteria. For goodness sake, The answer with +10 has nothing except  "Yes". It's basically, "We want to burn it. We have the power to do so. We're going to go ahead and do it, because we want it and have the power."

Answer (score -7):

The question was added new information claiming it satisfies all the criteria for burnination. Prima facie, it seems no effort is put into this claim.

> It fails all the preliminary checks before burnination:

> > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

> **No**, the tag is ambiguous and is equally applicable to:

> - branch protection (VCS)
> - access control
> - security measures

Is branch protection not a security measure? Is access control not a security measure? How is it ambiguous? Using different specific names for the same word doesn't make it ambiguous. We have a  specific [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) tag. There does seem to be a overlap with [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control). [access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-control) would indeed be a subdivision of [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection). The former requires a specific management system in place, based on user accounts, while the latter does not. It's important to note that both concepts described here and concepts like [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication),[authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization),[privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privacy), [integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrity), [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption), [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl) are all subdivisions of [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security). But, why aren't we burning [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security)? Inside [authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization), we have a more specific tag [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth). Inside [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth), we have subdivisions like [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth). Just because there are more specific tags available doesn't mean we should burn the parent. Do we burn [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth), because we have subdivisions like [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth)? Do we burn [authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization), because we have [oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth)? Or Do we burn [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security), because there are many specific tags available. No! Because, there might be concepts, not described by any of the subdivisions. And it helps to categorize all subdivisions in a single parent, making it easy to search. **Just because there are more specific subdivisions doesn't make the parent tag ambiguous by itself**. Does having names for Nissan or Ferrari make the term "Car" ambiguous?

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

> Yes and no, the concept can be on or off-topic depending on the context (questions about protection can be about security, general computing, or asked in a programming context).

That's vague. The same argument can be said of any tag. Let's take [python]. "Depending on context", say, The question is about learning python or getting a python book, the question is offtopic. Does that make the concept described, the language tag [python] off topic? Of course not. The real question is: Is the concept offtopic?

Does this definition, feel offtopic?

> Protection refers to any process that involves hiding the data or restricting access to the said data, such as "read only access", "write access", "copy access".

Does it at least attract offtopic questions more than other tags?  There is **zero evidence** to suggest that it does.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

> **No**, protecting something is a goal, while on-topic questions revolve around specific programming problems / algorithms that are often only circumstantially related to protection.

Again, the same thing can be said of any tag, if you add "something is a goal" to it. *Making a calculator in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is goal. [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)ing  something is a goal*.  Yes, it is. But it adds meaningful information to the tag. That the question is dealing with  that syntax and language. Maybe it's not about  accomplishing something. Maybe it's about debugging. Maybe it's about the why something is failing to trigger. The questions in [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) isn't necessarily about "protecting something".  Sometimes, it's about how to access protected resources.  Sometimes, it's about why protection fails in certain circumstances.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

> **No**, the only common meaning is that it is a process of restricting access to something which, as described above, can involve completely unrelated tasks.

If you read the above answer without the  "No", it's clear it means the same thing in all cases, *that it is a process of restricting access to something*. It means the same thing in all contexts.

Forget the law, The spirit of burnination criteria is this:

> Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?

> If a particular tag is bringing lots of off-topic posts to the site, then it certainly is harmful.

As said before, there's **zero, zilch, null evidence** to suggest it brings in any off-topic question. If it did, which it doesn't, the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071) says

> If the tag isn't harmful, consider instead a divide and conquer approach to the problem by using one or more of these alternative strategies:

> > Updating the tag wiki excerpt (an edit can be suggested by anyone, subject to approval)
> > Merging or renaming a tag (which can be handled instantly and painlessly by a moderator)
> > Adding/removing a tag synonym (which can also be handled instantly and painlessly by a moderator)

I've updated the tag wiki in a attempt to make the tag excerpt useful. But it is very strange, that just after updating the wiki, the post was updated, without due diligence to claim, it satisfies all the burnination criteria and that's with the grand-fathered +14 votes, making it easier to pass the +20 criteria, while answers defending it had to start from 0.

[Your distaste for a frustrating game shouldn't result in the destruction of otherwise-valid tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071)

Comment: "*Is branch protection not a security measure? Is access control not a security measure?*" branch protection is very different from access control. Both in how it's implemented and what the end goal is. Branch protection in VCS is more about controlling the process. Requiring reviewers, adding policies that need to be covered for some work to be added to a branch. It doesn't *hide* information or assume malicious actors. Mostly consistency and quality control. That's *not* what access control is - it's about securing a resource to only privileged access.

Comment: @VLAZ Great. As I already said, there seems to be a "overlap" with "access control", but not that "protection" is access control. Per my definition, `Protection refers to any process...hiding the data or restricting access to the said data,....`, Branch protection would come under "restricting access, specifically write access", based on certain policies.  The definition doesn't assume that there are malicious actors or that protection is **only** about "hiding data".[1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Protection can be from malicious actors or bad quality code writes and  ultimately it's about protecting the data against different type of negative things  threatening the data. The data needs to be safe from malicious actors as well as bad quality writes.

Comment: A garbage bin and a carpet both stop the floor from being dirty. I wouldn't really say they are both "dirt-protection". If you stretch any definition enough, it can cover disparate concepts. Both a car and a mug are sort of the same. They can roll. They can both hold liquids. But I don't really see how "branch protection" and "access control" are useful to combine in the same tag rather than separate ones.

Comment: @VLAZ I could say the same. Any definition can be compressed to be specific enough so that it can never cover the same concept. Mazda and Ferrari are different types of cars. You could make that difference and claim a tag is needed for both.  Even within the same Car,  there are different models of ferrari, you could claim a tag for each model for that difference. Even within the same model, age of the car maybe different. You could claim the tag for  each year for the same model. Where do you draw the line? Or rather how do you draw the line, based on what criteria?

Comment: There's no need to draw a line, we have meta for making the decision.

Comment: The ultimate criteria is Does it  attract offtopic questions? If you think they do, make your case and if it really does attract offtopic questions, more than other tags, I'll have no more case here.

Comment: Proof of it attracting off-topic questions isn't one of the 4 requirements of burnination, rather it is simply something that should be taken into account. There is no alternative solution that would make sense in this case given the tag is overly ambiguous and on it's own couldn't be used to ask an on topic question.

Comment: For all the talks about similarity, I also notice there is no mention on how the tag is *different* from [[tag:security]]. All the concepts you have described seem equally applicable to that tag. Where and *why* is there line drawn? Can there not be a similar line drawn between different sub-categories of the [[tag:protection]]?

Comment: @VLAZ Security encompasses various tags like [authentication], [authorization], [access-control], [cryptography] and you can't say how each one is different from [security] except that, they define a specific concept inside [security]. *Can there not be a similar line drawn between different sub-categories of the [protection]?* Yes, there is no question, there can be. But should it be drawn? If so, why? And if we did, should the parent be burninated? To flip the same question, why isn't [security] burninated, when there are so many sub categories present?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400126/

Comment: @TheMaster ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I wouldn't be opposed to breaking up [security]

Comment: @VLAZ  Would you also vouch for breaking up [authorization] to [oauth] and different types of authorization. Or  breaking up [arrays] to [c++-arrays], [java-arrays], [vba-arrays], [python-arrays] as   there are specific differences  between all of them?

Comment: I've never found [arrays] to be a particularly useful tag. The vast majority of times I encounter questions with it, they aren't even about arrays. Usually some basic question about loops or syntax. If not split up, I'd love it to be applied only where it actually matters. Because *actual* array operations tend to be uniform across languages. Some specifics might differ but swapping elements, or traversing, or sorting will involve the same steps. Described using different code. Protecting a branch and a resource is not the same thing to me.

Comment: @VLAZ `Protecting a branch and a resource is not the same thing to me` I'm sure some feel arrays aren't the same thing in different languages too.  Just like you feel the underlying concept and actual array operations being the same, I feel Branch protection is nothing but write access protection.  The goals maybe different -quality control and consistency, but the underlying process is "restricting access" until certain conditions are fulfilled. Furthermore, if many feel they're different, they can just create [branch-protection]  and use that and leave [protection] for other uses.

Comment: The place to draw the line is when there are skills specific enough to answer questions about it. "Protection" in general doesn't fit this. That is why I consider it too vague.

Comment: @Barett If you read my answer, I show why burning the parent tag is not advisable in such case(TLDR:Because, there might be concepts, not described by any of the subdivisions. And it helps to categorize all subdivisions in a single parent, making it easy to search). Another case against specific tags is if people needed specific tags, they would've created it by now. But there's no [branch-protection] so far unlike [access-control]. Not to mention, the volume of questions is so low, that dividing it up further isn't warranted. This is a concept tag  just like [arrays] and better left as is.

Comment: @Barett When Bhargav first edited your post in 2015, He says "there are 420 questions at present". 7 years later, we have 581 questions, a increase of barely 23 questions per year. Do you think that warrants splitting up the tag to different specific subdivisions?

Comment: "they would have created it by now" - this wasn't what I found when looking into this at the question level. Mostly people were lazy and just typed a few key words from their question. If that didn't come up, and the concept was included in the specific tag wikis, they might think a little harder and get someone who could actually help. The last part is key. Tags are for getting help from smes. I didn't see many cases where the protection tag would help with a search. The keyword was almost always located somewhere else already.