# What's the preferred tag for protection in spreadsheets?

Tags: discussion, tags

As [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection) was fated to be burned, I and SMEs in [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), after discussion  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296710/the-protection-tag-is-being-burninated#comment953857_424154) and [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/217630?m=55349153#55349153), decided to create [spreadsheet-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-protection) to save the categorization info, for high scoring questions in the tag. But, I found that all the questions that I tagged were untagged by a moderator (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70328246/revisions)) about 2 hours ago.

Are there objections to creating this tag too? Or is there a reason to burn this tag as well? If so, what's the preferred tag for categorizing protection related questions in spreadsheets?

Comment: Is there a need for such a tag? Why not just [tag:security]? That plus whatever spreadsheet technology should be enough to clue a viewer into something related to protection of sheets or cells, etc.

Comment: @TylerH Protection is a important feature in spreadsheets. Security means a lot of things(we have sharing, oauth, and like plenty of things related to the spreadsheet itself). Protection is a very specific subset of it.  We as SMEs unanimously agreed that such a tag was warranted. We even spent time [defending against [protection\] burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420781).  Question askers, also agree that such a tag was warranted, as can be seen in the great number of questions tagged [protection] with [google-sheets](I believe it was around 20% of the total, before burnination).

Comment: Furthermore, the only reason given, for [protection]  being burnt was because, "it was too broad". [security] is much worse in that case and [the  group for burnination already said they wouldn't be opposed to burning [security\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296710/the-protection-tag-is-being-burninated/420781#comment929753_420781)

Comment: If anything I'd go for document-protection, as on the Microsoft side, the read and write protection of Excel/Word/Powerpoint are extremely similar, if we need such a tag. I'd be strongly against using security, since these options are not about security at all but mostly for protection against accidental change (they can be undone in minutes by manipulating the file XML, in contrast to the encryption options these applications offer too)

Comment: @ErikA I see.  However, In Google's side of things, we have nothing similar in Google docs or slides. We only have protection in spreadsheets, which is similar to the [excel's worksheet level protection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6)(Honestly, the generic [protection] solved lot of these issues by providing a generic tag, which can be used for any type of protection)

Comment: How about the type-agnostic [file-protection]? Would apply equally well to files originating in Google Docs/Sheets as well as to Excel/Word files. It does run the danger of being misused by people who probably mean "permissions" or some other generic type of security, but there is already a [file-permissions] tag, so perhaps there won't be too much misuse there.

Comment: While I only removed one (I ran across it because you forgot to remove the [protection] tag), I wasn't keen on this tag myself. We had a small discussion in the mod room and it seemed like the tag was too granular (it seems silly to burninate one tag but introduce another with the same term). I'm not opposed to reversing course if there's some concrete reason to have the tag. I'm more or less in the same boat with TylerH's thinking there. If there's no better way to do it we can go back to that tag. I just wonder if we need a tag at all

Comment: @Machavity  The major reason shown for burning [protection] is that it referred to multiple different things - that it is "too broad". That's why a granular tag like [spreadsheet-protection] was created. I don't see the logic in burning this tag too, because it is "too granular" now. The intent was to maintain a easy to find top Frequent Qs list as well as searchability in "[google-sheets][protection]". What's the problem with creating a more specific/granular tag, especially when the parent was burnt for being "too broad"?

Comment: @TylerH  I'm not sure whether that would work.. [file-protection] in excel would probably refer to password protecting the entire file. There are other levels of protections inside excel itself:  Sheet and  range level. Google sheets protection would typically refer to sheet/range protection equivalent to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6 I synonymized many tags like, [google-sheets-conditionalformatting] in favour of generic tag: [conditional-formatting]; I'd hate to create a ultra specific tag like [google-sheets-protection]

Comment: I thiink I agree that [spreadsheet-protection] is probably the best path forward, given all the things said above and the fact that it means something specific in terms of spreadsheet applications. Just trying to work through other options so we don't miss something potentially obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some discussion on this, I think there is a stated use case for [spreadsheet-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-protection), and that the tag is not too granular. I would go back to using your preferred tag.

To elaborate: sometimes we see people creating tags that seem rather granular (i.e. making a tag for a specific function that sees little use) and we try to head that process off before it gets too large and we have to discuss burninations (yes, [there are people who will go on tagging sprees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356963/2370483)). Thus, we tend to err on the side of removing new tags that seem questionable. This is one of those rare times where the new tag was indeed worth keeping.

I have updated the burnination guidance to mesh with this. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.